# two index file within public_html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a web app where once the user logs in he is directed to a profile page. While building the front end I created both a login form and profile separately with its individual CSS and JS files in separate folders. Now while uploading to the server, the profile page is not able to access its CSS and JS files. This is how the files look like  after uploading in the server:

[image]

The index file in the pic is the index of the login page. I have the profile folder which contains all the CSS and JS files of the profile page. Its index file I have taken outside and named it profileindex.php. All the paths in the profileindex.php looks like this :-

```html
<link href="public_html/profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

The location tag from the authentication page is pointing to the profileindex.php:

```php
header('location: profileindex.php');
```

Please help as I am not able to access the CSS and JS of the profile page as expected. After login I can only see the profile page with its HTML components.

Comment: Remove the `public_html/` from this `<link href="public_html/profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">`

Comment: thanks for the input .I tried  the above link without public_html  already . Isnt working.

Comment: try visiting to www.yourdomain/profile/css/style.css from browser

Comment: Refresh the browser cache using `CTRL+F5`

Comment: thanks its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is incorrect.

Remove the `public_html` like so to use a relative path

```
<link href="profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Comment: thanks for the input .I tried with the above link already . Isnt working.

Comment: Did you remove the `/` before the word `profile`? Did you also refresh your browser cache by doing `CTRL+F5` as well

Comment: @DavidJorHpan its a little dangerous using short tags in an answer as these can be turned off

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `public_html` from the path as `profileindex.php` is already in this folder.

```
<link href="profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

Comment: thanks for the input .I tried with the above link already . Isnt working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="public_html/profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

This line looks for style.css file inside your current folder/public_html/profile/css/style.css.

Actual code should be:-

```
<link href="profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

This will look in current folder/profile/css/style.css.
Please Read about Absolute and relative paths [here](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

Comment: Fasionably late to the party, with the same answer as 2 others.

Comment: Important is not the answer but the explanation.. no use if the other guy doesn't gets it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the public_html/ from this

```
<link href="public_html/profile/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```